# Reference error : myname is not defined in Node JS (Visual code studio)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

**functions1.js (file 1)**

```
const myname = () => {

console.log("Hello");

};

module.export = myname;
```

**app.js (file 2)**

```
const sayname = require('./functions1');

myname();
```

> Reference error : myname is not defined

Comment: `const sayname = require('./functions1');` will import a `sayname` function, not `myname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be `module.exports = myname;`

```
const myname = () => {

console.log("Hello");

};

module.exports = myname;
```